# Replacing a single row in an R raster

Tags: r, r-raster

I am looking for the fastest way to assign new values to a whole row of a large raster.

I have a large raster called `ras`

```
> ras
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 71476, 49933, 3569011108  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 593235, 2091225, -3314375, -1170095  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=-18 +lat_2=-36 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=132 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : C:/Users/smithj/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiynZ5N/raster/r_tmp_2019-05-04_232648_206436_44436.grd 
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

And I have a vector of length `n=ncol` values called `newvals`. I generate `newvals` through a function that is not amenable to use with the `calc` function, but in the example below it is just a randomly generated vector for the purposes of this question.

```
#create example values 
newvals<-sample(0:100,49933, replace=TRUE)
```

My question is, if I wanted to replace the 7023rd row of `ras` with `newvals` is there a faster method than the one below?

```
#insert newvals into row 7023 of ras
ras[7023,]<-newvals
```

I have also looked at `setValues`, but it seems to only set values for a whole raster, not part of it(?). Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide much context. The problem is that you have a large dataset that is file-based, so any change will create a new file (unless you use `update`).

If you need to do this many times, for example row by row, you can open a new file for writing and write row by row (see `writeStart`). If it is only one row that needs to be changed, perhaps try your luck with `raster::update`.